# MySQL 8 trailing spaces being evaluated in equals comparison

Tags: mysql

I am getting different behaviors after updating a 5.6 database to 8.

On 5.6, if I run the following statement I get zero rows, which is what I expect to get:

```
SELECT * FROM EntityCustomerContact where CustomerContactID <> TRIM(CustomerContactID);
```

On 8.0 I get hundreds of rows returned. CustomerContactID is a varchar(32);

My understanding is that all CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT values in MySQL are *compared without regard to any trailing spaces*.

The update process consisted of importing a mysqldump from 5.6 into 8.0.  The only other thing that I changed other than moving to 8.0 was updating the collation on all tables and columns from **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** to **utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci**.  This is the first upgrade I've done moving to the utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci collation.

I have performed a number of other upgrades from 5.6/7 to 8.0 and never encountered this issue - I ran my test query on some other 8.0 (specifically 8.0.29) databases that were upgraded in the same fashion excepting the collation change and received the expected results.

I have searched for possible mysqld settings to address this but have come up short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL collations have a pad attribute, which has a value of PAD SPACE or NO PAD

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-binary-collations.html)

> For nonbinary strings (CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT values), the string
> collation pad attribute determines treatment in comparisons of
> trailing spaces at the end of strings. NO PAD collations treat
> trailing spaces as significant in comparisons, like any other
> character. PAD SPACE collations treat trailing spaces as insignificant
> in comparisons; strings are compared without regard to trailing spaces https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html

You have changed `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` and the following query return the PAD_ATTRIBUTE difference:

```
mysql> SELECT COLLATION_NAME, 
              PAD_ATTRIBUTE        
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS        
       WHERE CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'utf8mb4' 
       AND COLLATION_NAME in ('utf8mb4_unicode_ci','utf8mb4_0900_as_ci');

+--------------------+---------------+
| COLLATION_NAME     | PAD_ATTRIBUTE |
+--------------------+---------------+
| utf8mb4_0900_as_ci | NO PAD        |
| utf8mb4_unicode_ci | PAD SPACE     |
+--------------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been wondering about this.  Perhaps this explains it (from the changelog for 8.0.1):

> ----- 2017-04-10 8.0.1 Development Milestone -- Character Set Support -- -----
>
> The pad attribute for Unicode 9.0.0 collations was changed from PAD
> SPACE to NO PAD. Consequently, these collations now treat spaces at
> the end of strings like any other character. The affected collations
> have names that contain the string *0900*.
>
> Comparisons of [VARCHAR](/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html) columns that
> have a 9.0.0 collation differ from other collations with respect to
> trailing spaces. For example, 'a' and 'a ' compare as different
> strings, not the same string. Example:
>
> mysql> SET NAMES 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci';

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'a ';
+------------+
| 'a' = 'a ' |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
mysql> SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci';
mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'a ';
+------------+
| 'a' = 'a ' |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
```

> The INFORMATION_SCHEMA [COLLATIONS](/doc/refman/8.0/en/collations-table.html) table now has a
> PAD_ATTRIBUTE column that indicates the pad attribute for each
> collation.
>
> A problem with the latin1_de collation involving early weight string
> truncation has been corrected. The only likely effect is for
> [WEIGHT_STRING()](/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_weight-string)
> function results.

I think the bottom line is to avoid `CHAR`; stick with the `VARCHAR`.  I don't think `COLLATION` has much, if anything, to do with the issue; rather "Padding".

Comment: It's not the collation per se, but rather that in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS table they've changed the padding from PAD SPACE to NO PAD for utf8mb4_0900_as_ci, which seems like a fairly major breaking type of change: "For those cases where trailing pad characters are stripped or comparisons ignore them, if a column has an index that requires unique values, inserting into the column values that differ only in number of trailing pad characters results in a duplicate-key error. For example, if a table contains 'a', an attempt to store 'a ' causes a duplicate-key error."